# WP_Query on custom taxonomy works fine but fails if run through wp_ajax_

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, ajax

I'm using WP_Query to collate some info about posts based on their custom taxonomy.
My arguments are as follows:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    if ( isset($_POST['tag_id']) ) :
        $args['tax_query'] =
            array(array(
                'taxonomy' => 'region',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['tax_id'],
            ));
    endif;
```

Then I loop through and collate my data. And that works perfectly well. But because it's quite a heavy query, and appears for each taxonomy id I thought I'd run it on user demand and return the data with wp_ajax_

The same query seems to ignore all the tax_query arguments when returned through ajax. The arguments are the same and the correct "terms" is being passed. It's identical. I can't figure it out. Is this a bug? It's bugging me.

Updated to put the code in pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/rxSJ1C2n

The class is at the top, then the bit of jQuery I've put at the bottom but is actually in a separate file.

Comment: Without seeing a pastebin (or similar) of your whole ajax code, it's just guessing.

Comment: I've put it in pastebin now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see your call to the ajaxurl in your code.  Are you actually getting an ajax response?

Try this javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $("a.getviews").click( function() {
        var td = $(this).parent();
        /* only fetch results once */
        $(this).unbind('click').bind('click', function(){return false;});
        // replace button with loader
        $(td).html('<span class="loader"></span>');

        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: { action: "get_views", tax_id: td.attr("id") },
                success: function(response) {
                $("td").html(response);
                return false;                               
            }

            });

            });
    });
```

With large ajax responses I always have better luck buffering the output.

Add `ob_start();` before your loop then at the end add:

```
$response = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();

            echo $response;

                die(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me a few pointer - particularly to learn about `ob_start()`. However, it was all because of an error in my code. I'd been using `tag_id` in PHP and `tax_id` in JS.